# Is it possible to set multiple data attributes using the jQuery.attr() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This works:

```
$(myObj).attr("data-test-1", num1);
$(myObj).attr("data-test-2", num2);
```

But this doesn't:

```
$(myObj).attr({
  data-test-1: num1,
  data-test-2: num2
});
```

Am I missing something really obvious here?

Comment: Your second example produces a syntax error.

Comment: You cannot use dashes in object keys unless you delimit them as a string like `{"data-test-1" : "data"}`

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Sure, like this:

```
$(myObj).attr({"data-test-1": num1, "data-test-2": num2});
```

Like the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#setting-several-attrs) docs state:

> Setting several attributes at once
>
> To change the alt attribute and add the title attribute at the same
>   time, pass both sets of names and values into the method at once using
>   a plain JavaScript object. Each key-value pair in the object adds or
>   modifies an attribute:
>
> ```
> $('#greatphoto').attr({
>   alt: 'Beijing Brush Seller',
>   title: 'photo by Kelly Clark'
> });
> ```
>
> When setting multiple attributes,
>   the quotes around attribute names are optional.

Comment: "the quotes around attribute names are optional" only applies to camelCased properties, the OP wants to use dashes, quotes should be mandatory in this case -> `Unexpected token -`

Comment: @m90 - That's taken directly from the jQuery API, it's not my comment.

Comment: I'm aware of that but the dashes are what causes the OP's problems so I guess one should add that.

Comment: Since num1 and num2 are integers, do I need to pass them as num1.toString() as well?

Comment: I just tested that and it won't matter as the even `num1.toString()` still is stored as type Number.

Comment: This does not work or at least is failing on chrome. What does work is  $(myObj).data({"data-test-1": num1, "data-test-2": num2});

Comment: @tibc-dev - It still works fine, even in Chrome. Not sure what you're doing wrong without an example.

Answer (score 7):

Yes it is possible to setup multiple attributes, just use simple Object literal syntax. Example:

```
$('#my_image').attr({
  alt: 'Beijing Brush Seller',
  title: 'photo by Kelly Clark'
});
```

More info about attr method can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Comment: [JSON is not the same as Object literal syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation). What you're using is the latter.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for posting an answer to an already solved question after so many years.

I just thought about keeping the thread up to date with recommended solution<sup>***[citation needed]***</sup> as on date.

Since jQuery [`1.2.3`](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-key-value), there is a [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) function that takes arguments to get/set data attributes (setting multiple was available since [`1.4.3`](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-obj)) like this:

```
/* 
 ** In all the example below, note that 
 ** 'data-' is removed from attribute name
 */

// Setter (single)
$('#my_image').data('test-1', 'num1');
$('#my_image').data('test-2', 'num2');

// Setter (multiple)
$('#my_image').data({'test-1':'num1', 'test-2':'num2'});

// Getter (single)
$('#my_image').data('test-1');    // num1
$('#my_image').data('test-2');    // num2
```

***It must be noted that setting data attributes with `.data()` doesn't update the DOM, so you can't see these in the DOM inspector. Also, they are not cross compatible with `.attr()`. However, the data attributes set with `.attr()` can be retrieved with `.data()` (in short, any attributes that begin with 'data-' can be retrieved with `.data()`).***

```
// Setter
$('#my_image').attr('data-test-3', 'num3');    // note the 'data-' on attr name

// Getter
$('#my_image').data('test-3');    // num3
```

Comment: ```$('[data-id="5e4deced-0779-4dcd-ae23-d62a51817c1a"]').attr('data-ordinal', 5);
$('[data-id="5e4deced-0779-4dcd-ae23-d62a51817c1a"]').data('ordinal');
// Output -- 4
``` 
The `attr()` set does not update `data()`. So we need to update that separately.