# Pattern attr is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Here is my code

```
pattern.setAttribute('id','test');
pattern.setAttribute('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse');
pattern.setAttribute('width','10');
pattern.setAttribute('height','10');
```

in same code i have used like this,

```
pattern.attr('id','test','id','test','patternUnits','userSpaceOnUse','width','10','height','10');
```

but it's not working.. if i set the individual attribute using setAtribute working fine.. how to solve this. i want set attribute in single line. please find the jsfidle link
http://jsfiddle.net/ubLr4/18/

Comment: I think jquery lowercases everything and SVG is case sensitive. You'll have to write your own library function or modify jquery.

Comment: The jQuery version doesn't really accept an umlimeted amount of arguments, but you could pass in a map instead.

Comment: wouldn't jquery lowercase the map keys too?

Comment: Refer below  link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16422675/is-it-possible-to-set-multiple-data-attributes-using-the-jquery-attr-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no native DOM function that sets multiple attribute in one go, and jQuery's `attr` wouldn't be appropriate for your SVG element because it makes the attribute names lowercase. You can readily add a function of your own to do the same thing as jQuery's `attr` without lowercasing, though:

```
function setAttributes(element, attrs) {
    var name;
    for (name in attrs) {
        if (attrs.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            element.setAttribute(name, attrs[name]);
        }
    }
    return element;
}
```

Usage:

```
setAttributes(pattern, {
  id:'test',
  patternUnits: 'userSpaceOnUse',
  width: '10',
  height: '10'
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ubLr4/19/)

On most browsers (all modern ones), you could even add that to the `SVGElement` prototype:

```
SVGElement.prototype.setAttributes = function setAttributes(attrs) {
    var name;
    for (name in attrs) {
        if (attrs.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            this.setAttribute(name, attrs[name]);
        }
    }
    return this;
};
```

Usage:

```
pattern.setAttributes({
  id:'test',
  patternUnits: 'userSpaceOnUse',
  width: '10',
  height: '10'
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ubLr4/20/)

Comment: @RobertLongson: Thank you for keeping Rory and I on our toes re the SVG thing and attribute casing. V. much appreciated.